# All my JSSOR background banners stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor, banner

I have 3 pages with different banners sets, they are JSSOR slides and where working okay, but suddenly all of them stop working properly , the background is not showing up. What is this about? do they upgrade something in the plugin? can somebody from JSSOR help me?

Here are one of my pages
[Alpanel](http://www.alpanel.com/)

there isn't any JavaScript messages in the browser console, they are in diferent hosts , and actually I am building a new page in my localhost and last week it works, but now it doesn't

I just upload the banner in this link [Banner](http://treedigital.co/Banner-animado) if there is someone that can look it for me and let me know what happend, with  /js after domine you will find all js code like normal.

Comment: Can you post some code, preferably a minimal jsfiddle that reproduces your issue? If it remains in this state, this question will probably be closed.

Comment: Im so sorry I am new here so I'm not familiary with "minimal jsfiddle"  what I have to post? :/

Comment: Check out this article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It explains how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of code that reproduces your problem. Go to jsfiddle.com to work in a javascript/CSS/HTML "sandbox" that will allow you build a MVCE example, and share it here.

Comment: Ok, I am working on that, but  I have one more question, whit the pluging works like 4 .js  diferents docs, Do I have to copy&paste all in the same box or is there a way to place them separetely,   and there is a code <script> that should be in the html page, can i leave it there or where I sholud place it, Sorry for my english i am spanish speaker :/

Comment: Put the link to the source (e.g. http://some.place.com/path/something.js) in the **External Resources** as explained here: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#external-resources

Comment: Im not sure , what i might doing rong here, the animation is not working, here is  the link: https://jsfiddle.net/fLyr0ynx/#&togetherjs=8wnI1lMGPq